# Show last node of every term in one Views

Tags: views, 8, theming

How to show the last node of every term using only one View? That's what I want to get:

`news/football` - last node of the football term

`news/boxing` - last node of boxing term.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

1. Contextual Filter -> Content: Has taxonomy term ID
2. When the filter value is not in the URL -> Provide value -> Type: Taxonomy item ID from URL
3. Relatoinships -> does not necessarily.

Works perfect: Drupal core 8.6.1

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a view to show content
2. Add page display and set path setting to *news/%*
3. Add contextual filter "Has taxonomy term ID"
4. Add sort criteria "Authored on (desc)"
5. In pager settings check "Display a specified number of items" and set "Items per page" setting to 1.

Note that this will produce URLs with numeric term IDs (i.e. *news/123*).
To make use of term names you need to configure a relationship to the term so you get the information about the term into view, then use term name contextual filter.

Comment: I already have a `news/boxing` page where the last 10 nodes are displayed. I want to show the last node in the block views above them. Now in each term the same node is displayed....

Comment: Just wanted to add that you don't need a separate module to get term name in the URL, you just have to add a Relationship to the term so you get all the information about the term into views, then use term name contextual filter.

Comment: To remove the latest node from the list of 10 and only keep it in your Block, edit the views that creates the 10 list and set the paging offset to 1.

Comment: This works perfect on my **Latest from author* page with contextual filter: Content: Author but I tried everything and this does not works with taxonomy terms. I tried to use a lot filters - Content: Has taxonomy term name with Depth, Content: Has taxonomy term ID, Content: Category  (field_category). Nothing...

Comment: @prkos, good point. I've updated the answer.